# When to use 'had been' + past participle of the verb

Tags: past-participles, past-perfect

I read the sentence below in a news article:

> "The couple had been engaged since the summer," her spokeswoman said in a statement.

Why was "had been engaged" used in this sentence. Is it wrong to say "The couple *have* been engaged since the summer"?  Is this sentence in passive voice so "had been + past participle" used?

PS: I read other questions on stackexchange about tenses, but I couldn't understand why was had been + past participle used in the sentence.

Comment: You're leaving out a crucial piece of information in this question ... they're no longer engaged, they're married.

Comment: had+been+present participle=past perfect continuous tense had+past participle= past perfect tense had+been+past participle=passive form of past perfect tense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context this is a little difficult, but one reason it could be written this way is that the couple is no longer engaged. To amend the sentence for clarity:

> "The couple had been engaged since the summer," her spokeswoman said in a statement, "but now they have ended the relationship."

edit: I believe this is referred to as the [Past Perfect Progressive](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_perfect_progressive.htm) tense (or *Past Perfect Continuous*)

Comment: +1: In fact, if you google the quote, you will discover that they're no longer engaged, because they married in a secret ceremony.

Comment: @Peter Shor Then I suppose my hypothetical amendment is inaccurate :).

Comment: Makes sense- using "have been" in the statement would be wrong, because the statement is not true (because they got married) NOW. Is the word "engaged" acting as adverb or verb? (I think it is acting as adverb modifying the verb been)

Comment: @Alex "Engaged" is an adverb here. It's never a verb when referring to betrothal. You "get engaged" or "are engaged" or "she is engaged". Only in another sense of the word - "I engaged him in combat" - does it become a verb.

Comment: If you decline @Marcus_33's reading, the *be* is the passive auxiliary and this is Past Perfect Passive; if you accept that reading, the *be* is a simple copula and it's Past Perfect.

Comment: @Marcus_33  I think you mean adjective, not adverb. And I think what we have here is not a simple adjective but a stative passive of the verb *engage* in the original sense of 'pledge'. The participle in a stative passive is, to be sure, functionally indistinguishable from an adjective; but the verbal sense lurks behind it.